# How to set an Object's values inside an array with ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm looking for the quickest and most resource friendly way of setting an Object's values inside an array. Can use ES6 syntax as well.

So let's say I have this array of objects:

```
let group = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Test 1',
        geo: 'Japan',
        car: 'Toyota'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Test 2',
        geo: 'USA',
        car: 'Tesla'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Test 3',
        geo: 'Germany',
        car: 'Audi'
    }
];
```

And I want to get one of these objects based on user input. Let's say we want to get the 3rd item's index by Obejct's ID:

```
let index = group.findIndex(g => g.id === payload.id);
```

Once I have the index I want to assign new values to this object like this:

```
group[index].id = payload.id;
group[index].name = payload.name;
group[index].geo = payload.geo;
group[index].car = payload.car;
```

However it is long, ugly, and imagine if you'd have 50+ values inside this object.

**Question:** Is there any shorter and more efficient way of achieving the same? Including ES6-ES7 syntaxes also.

Comment: Are the ids unique? I mean, if so, you may not require getting the index at all and the solution would become briefer.

Comment: @vahdet Yep, the IDs are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for changing the properties of the found object.

```js
var group = [{ id: 1, name: 'Test 1', geo: 'Japan', car: 'Toyota' }, { id: 2, name: 'Test 2', geo: 'USA', car: 'Tesla' }, { id: 3, name: 'Test 3', geo: 'Germany', car: 'Audi' }],
    payload = { id: 3, name: 'update', geo: 'Germany Bavaria Ingolstadt', car: 'Audi 1' },
    object = group.find(({ id }) => id === payload.id);

if (object) {
    Object.assign(object, payload);
}

console.log(group);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect works as expected. Thank you so much for this! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Above given solution is correct, You can also do same using map in a single line (prefer to use lodash map function).

```
let group = [{ id: 1, name: 'Test 1', geo: 'Japan', car: 'Toyota' }, { id: 2, name: 'Test 2', geo: 'USA', car: 'Tesla' }, { id: 3, name: 'Test 3', geo: 'Germany', car: 'Audi' }],
payload = { id: 3, name: 'update', geo: 'Germany Bavaria Ingolstadt', car: 'Audi 1' }; 

group = group.map((item) => item.id === payload.id ? payload : item);
```

Comment: What's important to note is that in this solution you will REPLACE the entire object with a new one, while in Nina's and mine solution 1) you are replacing only values of keys which are in both objects (`payload` and `group[i]`)  2) values which keys are only in one of those will stay in new object.

Answer (score 1):

```
el = group.find(g => g.id === payload.id);
if (el) { // add this 'if' if you are not sure if payload's id will be in group
  idx = group.indexOf(el);
  group[idx] = {...el, ...payload};
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use `.find` to locate an object then use the object to...locate the index. That's parsing the array two times. You can either change `el` which already changes the array or `findIndex` to just grab the index. Then setting the index to a *new* object means the old one would be garbage collected. Or worse - not GCed because something already referenced it and it now doesn't get the update.

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing. For one-time search&update the Array.find works well. But if you need to update more than one entry you have to build an array index.

```js
(function(){
    let group = [{ id: 1, name: 'Test 1', geo: 'Japan', car: 'Toyota' }, { id: 2, name: 'Test 2', geo: 'USA', car: 'Tesla' }, { id: 3, name: 'Test 3', geo: 'Germany', car: 'Audi' }],
        payload = { id: 3, name: 'update', geo: 'Germany Bavaria Ingolstadt', car: 'Audi 1' };
        
    let groupIndex = {};
    group.forEach(x => groupIndex[x.id]=x);

    let start = new Date().valueOf();
    let id = 1;
    let updates = 1000000;
    for(let i=0;i<updates;i++)
        if (groupIndex[id])
            Object.assign(groupIndex[id], payload);

    console.log(updates+" taken "+(new Date().valueOf()-start)+" ms");
})()
```